# How to take standard input from user and use that across Appium Test Case?

Tags: java, selenium, awt, appium

I have a scenario where I want to take User Standard Input from the console *(Using Scanner(System.in) utility in Java)*.

Like, When a particular text field is being appeared then User need to type the input text as standard input rather than a device itself.

I am trying below code:

```
System.out.println("Enter the User Input: ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputForTextField = sc.next();
getTextField().sendKeys(inputForTextField);
```

But the execution is getting stuck on `String inputForTextField = sc.next();` User is not able to enter the text on the console and **after 60 seconds Appium session is getting timed out.**

Any help/suggestion would really be appreciated!

*I am also open to hearing suggestion if I can take input from User using some Java AWT prompt, I just wanted to take user input from the computer rather than the device itself.*

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have your reasons, but doesn't the inclusion of user interaction defeat the purpose of automation?

Comment: Hi @BillHileman, It's not complete Automation I am using, so I nee Human Intervation.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the values using dataprovider(Excel/Json files) or even using config.properties file. In automation, it is machine which does all the inputs, human intervention defeats the automation purpose.